# React Native Windows: play a video from C:/

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

I'm trying to play a video from my local storage (C:/) in my ReactNative Windows app. I've tried the following to no avail:

- [React Native File Viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-viewer) I thought this would be the easy alternative, however my RNW version is 0.69, and support for this library has not been updated in 5 years (which mean autlinking is not available). When I try to build the app after adding the library with `npm install`, I get the following error:

> RootRoute\node_modules\react-native-file-viewer\windows\RNFileViewer\RNFileViewerModule.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ReactNative' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [RootRoute\node_modules\react-native-file-viewer\windows\RNFileViewer\RNFileViewer.csproj]. Check your build configuration.

- Linking: There is way to open URLs in ReactNative called Linking. However this will not work with local files, only with youtube videos and such. It goes something like this:

  ```
  import {Linking} from 'react-native';

  openLinkMethod () {
      Linking.openURL(url)
  }
  ```
- [WebView](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview): I've tried creating a WebView and a little HTML to source the video like this

  ```
               <WebView
               source={{ html: `<h1><video width="320" height="240" controls>
               <source 
                   src="file://route/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
               <source src="../videos/big.webm" type="video/ogg">
               Your browser does not support the video tag.
               </video></h1>` }}
               style={{ marginTop: 20, width: 300, height: 300 }}
               />
  ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by copying the video to my local app folder and using the library react-native-video.

The property `RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath` is a local AppData folder which you can user to store the video and read it with `file://` directive in a `<Video/>` tag.